# Почему к инпуту не добавляется псевдоэлемент?

Tags: html, css

`::after` не работает.

```css
input {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
}

input:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 27px;
  height: 21px;
  background: red;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1ygc5Lkb/

Comment: Replaced elements. Некоторое время назад в хроме работали псевдоэлементы с инпутами, потом выпилили.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Псевдо-элементы `:after` и `:before` могут быть применимы только для элементов-контейнеров, потому что они рендерятся как дочерние элементы. `input` элемент не является элементом-контейнером.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо создать контейнер для `input`, и к этому контейнеру применять псевдо-элементы

Пример

```css
.input-container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}
.input-container:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -10.5px;
    width: 27px;
    height: 21px;
    background: red;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    pointer-events: none;
}
input {
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```